# changing the row location and add row and column total

Tags: r

suppose I have a data frame named "df". I am having trouble adding total column and row and changing the location of row including "non" . my expected output would be like df1.
thanks.

```
df<- data.frame(x =c("non",1,2,3,4), y= c(4,3,2,1,5), z= c(0,3,2,0,1))

df1<-

        x     y    z    total
  1     1     3    3      7
  2     2     2    2      6
  3     3     1    0      4
  4     4     5    1     10
  5    non    4    0      4
total  10     15   6     31
```

Comment: Change "non" to NA, then use rowSums, colSums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take help of `janitor::adorn_totals` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(x) %>%
  mutate(index = row_number(), .before = 1, 
         x = as.numeric(na_if(x, 'non'))) %>%
  janitor::adorn_totals(where = c("row", "col"), na.rm = TRUE)

# index  x  y z Total
#     1  1  3 3     7
#     2  2  2 2     6
#     3  3  1 0     4
#     4  4  5 1    10
#     5 NA  4 0     4
# Total 10 15 6    31
```